# How to pass arguments to command line build task in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Can anyone briefly explain to me how to add build and pass arguments to command line build task in VSTS (TFS Online) or suggest me some good links?

Comment: Are you looking for https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/steps/utility/command-line?

Comment: That URL has some incorrect characters in it. Try this one https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/steps/utility/command-line

Answer (score 0):

The build task is actually a wrapper around MSBuild. So whatever you can achieve using MSBuild, can be passed to the build task.

[MSBuild Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393574(v=vs.120).aspx)